# Implementation of an integral formula for an a posteriori estimate in pymc3

Tags: python, pymc

I am trying to fit a model according to some data.

The data I have are supposed to obey the following formula:
$$\mu_g(t) = (\mu_0 + \frac{\alpha_g}{\delta_g})\exp(-\delta_g t) + \frac{\alpha_g}{\delta_g}
+ \frac{\beta_g}{\delta_g} \exp(-\delta_g t)
\int_0^t \exp(-\delta_g \tau) \frac{\eta(\tau)}{\gamma_g+\eta(\tau)} d\tau$$

The parameters are as follows: $(\alpha_g, \beta_g, \gamma_g, \delta_g)$ for $g \in \{1, \cdots, 12\}$ and $\eta_k$ for $k \in \{1, \cdots, 11\}$.
That is, we assume $\eta$ is only known at some points in time, and the integral is computed *via* a quadrature formula, for instance the trapezoid rule.

I tried to implement the procedure in Python using the `pymc` library, without prior knowledge of it. I read a good part of the documentation, and totally the get started [page](https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/getting_started).

I came up with the following code

```py
from io import BytesIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.style.use('seaborn-darkgrid')
import pymc3 as pm

print('Running on NumPy v{}'.format(np.__version__))
print('Running on PyMC3 v{}'.format(pm.__version__))

exprbin = open('../data/data.txt').read().replace(',','.').encode()
expr = np.genfromtxt(BytesIO(exprbin), missing_values = 'NA', filling_values = np.nan, skip_header = 1)
C, R, T, G = 2, 4, 11, 12
exprcrtg = expr[ : , 3 : ].reshape(C, R, T, G)

time = np.array([0., 0.5, 1., 3.5, 6.5, 9.25, 12.5, 18.5, 22.5, 26.5, 30.5])

with pm.Model() as basic_model:

    # Priors for unknown model parameters
    alpha = pm.HalfNormal('alpha', sd = 10, shape = G)
    beta  = pm.HalfNormal('beta' , sd = 10, shape = G)
    gamma = pm.HalfNormal('gamma', sd = 10, shape = G)
    delta = pm.HalfNormal('delta', sd = 10, shape = G)
    eta   = pm.HalfNormal('eta'  , sd = 10, shape = T)
    sigma = pm.HalfNormal('sigma', sd = 10, shape = G)

    # Expected value of outcome
    alpha2 = alpha[np.newaxis, : ]
    beta2  = beta [np.newaxis, : ]
    gamma2 = gamma[np.newaxis, : ]
    delta2 = delta[np.newaxis, : ]
    eta2   = eta  [ : ,np.newaxis]
    time2  = time [ : ,np.newaxis]
    mu0    = np.nanmean(exprcrtg[ : , : , 0, : ], axis = (0, 1))
    etagammapluseta2 = eta2 / (gamma2 + eta2)
    integral = np.trapz(np.exp(delta2*time2) * etagammapluseta2, time2, axis = 0)
    mu       = (mu0 - alpha2/delta2)*np.exp(-delta2*time2) + alpha2/delta2 + beta2*np.exp(-delta2*time2)/delta2*integral

    # Likelihood (sampling distribution) of observations
    Y_obs = pm.Normal('Y_obs', mu = mu, sd = sigma, observed = exprcrtg)

# Maximum a posteriori estimate
map_estimate = pm.find_MAP(model = basic_model)

print(map_estimate)
```

I get the following error:
`IndexError: list assignment index out of range` at line
`integral = np.trapz(np.exp(delta2*time2) * etagammapluseta2, time2, axis = 0)`.

To eliminate the possibility of a trival error, I've tried this bit of code outside of the `pm.Model()` and it shows no error.

So my guess is that I am making a wrong use of `pm.Model()` but I have no clue as to what it could be.